# Else, If statement breaking

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, if-statement, sql-update

The first if statement works but when you try and execute the else statement it breaks on: `int SearchUser = Convert.ToInt32(SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);`

```
protected void SearchResult_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // open new connection
    SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    connection1.Open();

    int SearchUser = Convert.ToInt32(SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
    int Student = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);


    if (SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text != null)
    {

    String PT = "INSERT into PTutors(PersonalTutorID, StudentID) values(@SearchUser, @Student)";
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(PT, connection1);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchUser", SearchUser);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student", Student);
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    Response.Write("alert('Student Assigned to Personal Tutor');");
    Response.Write("document.location.href='ViewAssignedTutors.aspx';");
    Response.Write("</script>");
    }

    else 
    { 

    int SearchAPM = Convert.ToInt32(SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text);

        String PT2 = "INSERT into PTutors(PersonalTutorID, StudentID) values(@SearchAPM, @Student)";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(PT2, connection1);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchAPM", SearchAPM);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student", Student);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
        Response.Write("alert('Student Assigned to Personal Tutor');");
        Response.Write("document.location.href='ViewAssignedTutors.aspx';");
        Response.Write("</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the exception message? you say it breaks, but not what the error is? i'm going to take a guess - does `SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text` contain a value that can be turned into an integer?

Comment: The error message is: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: what is the value of the text field you are trying to turn into an integer?

Comment: i think this line may throwing the error `SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text`

Comment: can find something from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858076/an-exception-of-type-system-formatexception-occurred-in-mscorlib-dll-but-was-n)

Comment: what the value you get first time in `int SearchUser` ?

Comment: This is an overly bloated amount of code--please trim it down to minimal example that is complete, runnable, and reproduces the error.

Comment: if value not set, text value can contains empty string not only null

Comment: We are trying to assign to 2 different UserIDs. We can assign to the first userID, which is the if statement but when we try to assign to the second UserID which is the else statement the code breaks at that code line ^^. Seems like it breaks because there is no value in SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text. But there shouldn't be a value here it should be pulling through int SearchAPM = Convert.ToInt32(SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text);

Comment: Ben - how can the code be trimmed down?

Comment: @LishaMcNally you need to make sure that `SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[9]` actually contains a value that can be turned into an integer. nobody can magic that away if it is something that isn't a number.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of terse

```
  int SearchAPM = Convert.ToInt32(SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text);
```

put talkative

```
  int SearchAPM = 0;

  if (!int.TryParse(SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text, out SearchAPM)) {
    Message.Show(String.Format("\"{0}\" is not an integer value.", 
      SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text));
  }
```

then, please, have a look at message popped up and debug the routine;

Answer (score 0):

It seems that data you are trying to convert is not in a proper format. As described on [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Try placing a breakpoint on the converts, and see which values you are giving from the cells. Also, how did you determine that you should use field 9 ? Are you sure you are not just selecting the wrong field?

Alternatively you can also encase your converts in a try catch

```
try{
    int SearchAPM = Convert.ToInt32(SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text);
} catch(FormatException ex)
{
   // Do something to debug/handle
   SearchApm = -1;
   Trace.WriteLine("Oh no, {0} is not correctly formated",SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text);
}
```

Or to even simplify version of such a try catch could be the [try parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will handle the error internally, giving you a 0 if it fails.